# Empty $_POST for <select> tag

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to take `$_POST['category']` from a `<select>` tag, but it's empty!

**HTML**

```
<form name="report" method="post" action="">
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>
            <select name="category" form="report">
                <option value="one">Option 1</option>
                <option value="two">Option 2</option>
            </select>
        </th>
     </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**PHP** (at the top of the page)

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    die($_POST['category']);
}
```

Once submitted, the page is empty (died with an empty variable). Other variables in the same form work correctly (such as `<input>` and `<textarea>`). I'm using PHP 5.2.17

Comment: Your code doesn't have a submit button. That generally helps.

Comment: Where is `<input type='submit' name='submit'>`?

Comment: The form attribute references forms via id not name, and the select is already in the form...

Comment: Yes I do, I didn't show it in the code. `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">`

Comment: @Musa When changed to `<select id="category">` I get the same results

Comment: I meant, the attribute `form="id-of-a-form"` references a form via its id.

Comment: You don't even want that `form=''` attribute...

Comment: @JoshuaGeorge update your question with your submit input, are you sure it's inside the `<form>`?

Comment: `form="report"` is not valid. the `form` attribute doesn't exist in a html 4.01 DTD under `!ATTLIST SELECT`, i'm guessing is that it is confusing the browser?

Comment: Removing the form="" attribute and refreshing _(not resubmitting)_ did solve the problem

Comment: @zamnuts the [`form`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/select.html#select.attrs.form) attribute is html5

Answer (score 0):

Well your question is missing a submit button but you need to do this:

```
<form name="report" method="POST">
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>
            <select name="category" form="report">
                <option value="Option 1" title="Option 1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="Option 2" title="Option 2">Option 2</option>
            </select>
        </th>

        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' />

     </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['submit']` is not set because your form has no input element named *submit*. This leads to `die($_POST['category'])` not being executed. This leads to your PHP script not producing any output.